# Method for creating a bulge in a fuselage

Tags: modeling

What method would you suggest I use to create, as best I can describe it, the "bulge" or streamlined c-shape add-on found under some commercial aircraft (see the underside of an Airbus A320, or a Citation Latitude as examples)

I have the fuselage (cylinder) modeled, and am now stuck at how to go about adding this c-shaped bulge under and attached to the the fuselage with its well-defined crease along the top where it meets the round-face of the tapering (to the rear) fuselage, and then its gets a streamlined shape at the bottom, front, and back. I have the aircraft's blueprints, so I know its size, location, dimensions, etc. but the method for adding this is my stumbling block for now.

I've added a couple of images to show what the end result should look like, so hope that helps.

What's the best method and tools you'd suggest I use in Blender to get this done? 
(I have both v2.7 and the 2.8 beta -- so can use suggestions for either version)

Thanks for the help!

[image: back view]
[image: Front view]
[image: side view under-fuselage bulge]

Answer (score 1):

Hard to do it without a complete blueprint, but I guess you can do it this way:

- Create the right view profile, which is basically an extruded cylinder.
- Draw the wing cut with the knife.
- Extrude the wing, use all the views to make it correctly.

[image]

Comment: There is an extension downward from the fuselage along the boundary (see the front view pic).The circle of the fuselage it goes into is "hidden" in this extension (which wraps around the fuselage in a box-like fashion).  THEN the wing is extruded from that vertical surface. The extension is not part of the wing. It is a (streamlined) box-like wrap around the fuselage (see the front view pic attached)..and that forms around the fuselage for that streamlined look.  I need to first create this streamline box-bulge under the fuselage. Then extruding the wing from it should be the easy part.

Comment: I dont't see a big difference, just change a bit the topology underneath so that it fits the profile you want... also, note that it would help if you could provide a complete blueprint with top, right and front view of the same plane

Comment: is the Cessna CJ4 the kind of profile you're referring to? I've edited my answers

Comment: Yep-- the Cj4 is the same idea. Refer to the A320 also -- similar kinda thing. The problem is that the wing extrudes from the bulge, its not part "the" bulge. Its almost like there are 2 separate pieces.

Comment: yes so you can either separate the wing or add some edge loops to sharp the angles...